# Call a servlet to write data in JSON format to a URL in the server

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, web

I'm trying to call a Servlet that writes the javaobject taken from database in json format from another Servlet.

The flow of my code is Servlet1 `check_login` -> Servlet2 `jsonCreate`

I'm getting HTTP 404 error when I try to do that.

Here is my check_login.java Servlet code

```
 @WebServlet("/Check_login")
public class Check_login extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user_name=request.getParameter("user_name");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");

    try {

        String role=check_database(user_name,password);
        if(role.equals("")) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.html");
        }else if(role.equals("admin")) {

            List<Programs> Programs_Offered = new ArrayList<Programs>();
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsonCreate");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }else if(role.equals("mac")) {
            response.sendRedirect("mac_welcome.jsp");
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And, here is jsonCreate.java Servlet code

```
@WebServlet("/jsonCreates.json")
public class jsonCreate extends HttpServlet {

public static List<Programs> list() throws SQLException, IOException {


    List<Programs> Programs_Offered = new ArrayList<Programs>();

    Connection conn=DataBase_Connection.getInstance().getConnection();
    Statement ps=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(Queries.view_programs);


    while(rs.next()){
        Programs p=new Programs();
        p.setProgramName(rs.getString("ProgramName"));
        p.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
        p.setApplication_Eligibility(rs.getString("Applicant_Eligibility"));
        p.setDuration(rs.getInt("Duration"));
        p.setDegree_Certificate_Offered(rs.getString("Degree_Certificate_Offered"));
        Programs_Offered.add(p);    
    }
    return Programs_Offered;
    }

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public jsonCreate() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Programs> categories=null;
    try {
        categories = jsonCreate.list();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String categoriesJson = new Gson().toJson(categories);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(categoriesJson);
    //response.sendRedirect("admin_welcome.jsp");
}
```

when I make the name of jsonCreates.json same as java servlet Name (jsonCreate) it runs fine and opens the json data on page at URL `http://localhost:8081/servlet_demo/jsonCreate`.

Then again when I re-direct to a new JSP `admin_welcome.jsp` it opens without any problem but I don't find any json data available in the link `http://localhost:8081/servlet_demo/jsonCreate`.

I'm commiting some mistake and I'm not able to find it. Can someone tell what's missing in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the name of jsonCreates.json same as java servlet Name (jsonCreate)

```
   @WebServlet("/jsonCreate")
```

The reason why you dont get the json data is because response.sendRedirect() does not forward any data, it just makes a redirection(navigation) to a page.

If you want your JSON data to be accessible throughout your page navigations then you should create a session and set a session variable to hold this json data.

JAVA

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("variable", "json value");
response.sendRedirect("/page");
```

JSP

```
<%
    out.println(session.getAttribute("variable"));
%>
```

**OR**

you can use forward() as below:

JAVA

```
request.setAttribute("variable", "JSON data");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

JSP

```
<%
    out.println(request.getAttribute("variable"));
%>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to write it in a url with .json format instead of saving it into a attribute variable?